# How to color a button with stripes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to color the button like in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Most likely, where did you get stuck?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Just create an SVG.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I was about to write an in-depth answer but the question was closed. Here you go: https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/gOQMQWj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a few divs and wire it all up with CSS.

Since you will be using borders for each stripe, setting the `box-sizing` to `border-box` is important here. This way everything aligns correctly.

```js
document.querySelector('.rainbow-button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }

body {
  background: #505661;
}

.rainbow-button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 4em;
  min-height: 4em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 2rem; /* Make it 2x the size */
}

.rainbow-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rainbow-button,
.rainbow-button .stripes,
.rainbow-button .stripe,
.rainbow-button .value {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* The most important rule */
}

.rainbow-button .stripes,
.rainbow-button .value {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rainbow-button .stripe {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.15em solid grey;
}

.rainbow-button .stripe:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.667em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.667em;
}
.rainbow-button .stripe:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.667em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.667em;
}
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(1) { border-color: #33A9D9; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(2) { border-color: #32C475; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(3) { border-color: #DDD237; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(4) { border-color: #CB4A4F; }

.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(1) { border-color: #3abef2; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(2) { border-color: #3ef28f; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(3) { border-color: #f2e63c; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(4) { border-color: #f2595e; }

.rainbow-button .value {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 100;
  text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.1em black; /* For contrast */
}

.rainbow-button:hover .value {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="rainbow-button">
  <div class="stripes">
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="value">4</div>
</button>
```

Alternatively, you can make the stripes `flex:1` and eliminate the `width:25%` from the equation:

```css
.rainbow-button .stripes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rainbow-button .stripe {
  flex: 1;
  border: 0.15em solid grey;
}
```

Now we do not have to worry about percentages:

```js
document.querySelector('.rainbow-button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5rem !important; }

body {
  background: #505661;
}

.rainbow-button {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 4em;
  min-height: 4em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 2rem; /* Make it 2x the size */
}

.rainbow-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rainbow-button,
.rainbow-button .stripes,
.rainbow-button .stripe,
.rainbow-button .value {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* The most important rule */
}

.rainbow-button .stripes,
.rainbow-button .value {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rainbow-button .stripes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rainbow-button .stripe {
  flex: 1;
  border: 0.15em solid grey;
}

.rainbow-button .stripe:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.667em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.667em;
}
.rainbow-button .stripe:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.667em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.667em;
}
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(1) { border-color: #33A9D9; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(2) { border-color: #32C475; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(3) { border-color: #DDD237; }
.rainbow-button .stripe:nth-child(4) { border-color: #CB4A4F; }

.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(1) { border-color: #3abef2; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(2) { border-color: #3ef28f; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(3) { border-color: #f2e63c; }
.rainbow-button:hover .stripe:nth-child(4) { border-color: #f2595e; }

.rainbow-button .value {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 100;
  text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.1em black; /* For contrast */
}

.rainbow-button:hover .value {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="rainbow-button">
  <div class="stripes">
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
    <div class="stripe"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="value">4</div>
</button>
```